# IMGKit gem generate unexpected values in image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imgkit

I'm using imgkit gem to create JPGs and PNGs from HTML, it is working fine in development, but in production server it does not showing text in images instead showing boxes other than text.

[Example can be seen here](https://lister-api.droidox.com/system/images/local_images/001/445/665/original/8002__ITEMIMAGEURL2.png?1512718108)